# Converting an Objective-C framework to Swift - Header files still displaying Objective-C functions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I converted my entire `Objective-C` framework to `Swift`. After building it, when I check the framework's Header files, it is still displaying the old `Objective-c` functions.
I deleted all the `Objective-C` files from the framework project. I have tried cleaning and building the project. But with no success.

Comment: Did you try deleting the DerivedData folder?

Answer (score 1):

You deleted the Objective-C files from the Xcode project, but did you also remove them from the file system and any source control you might be using?

Also, your Build Settings in your Xcode project can be searching for library/header files even after you've removed them from explicit inclusion in the *Project Navigator* in Xcode.

Just make sure the search paths don't look for old Obj-C stuff. Be careful of recursive searches like `MyXcodeProject/**`. The `**` will recursively search all subfolders and their subfolders for things to include.

Better to specify folders directly in the search paths if you can. If you know you don't need search paths, you can just clear them all.

[image]

...although, you may want to leave the default exclusions in place:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Remember that you can't subclass a Swift class in Objective-C.
>   Therefore, the class you migrate can't have any Objective-C
>   subclasses.
>
> Once you migrate a class to Swift, you must remove the corresponding
>   .m file from the target before building to avoid a duplicate symbol
>   error.
>
> To make a Swift class available in Objective-C, make it a descendant
>   of an Objective-C class.
>
> Command-click a Swift class name to see its generated header.
>
> Option-click a symbol to see implicit information about it, like its
>   type, attributes, and documentation comments.

from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective-c_code_to_swift

Also, delete your DerivedData, do a clean build and restart the xCode.

Answer (score 0):

How can you see "Header" files in Swift based framework even after removing Obj C files. Definitely there's the build issue. If build is proper, then you are not referring/using to the right framework (in the app) after building it. This is most common mistake that I observed with many developers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, try it on your framework's Target **Build Settings**:

- Disable modules (Enable modules (C and Objective-C))

[image: Disable modules]

- Make sure the Swift version is set (Swift Language Version)

[image]